# Define and access an array in x86 assembly TASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, tasm

I am trying for hours and hours to access an array in assembly x86 TASM using dosbox - but I always get 'Operand types do not match' or 'Pointer expression needs brackets' error - I've searched the whole internet and couldn't find something that works in TASM x86.. this is the code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
A DB 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11 
; --------------------------
CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
mov al,A[0]

; --------------------------

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Changing the line to:

```
mov ax, BYTE PTR A[0]
```

or to:

```
mov ax,  A[BYTE PTR 0]
```

And even changing ax or al with all these combinations is failing.. or trying to acces the OFFSET of array A:

```
mov al, A[OFFSET A]
```

I don't know where's the problem..

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Just `mov al, A[0]` should work.  After all, `A` is an array of bytes.  Sadly I don't have a copy of TASM to test this.  It's a very outdated assembler; you should consider using something modern like nasm instead.

Comment: mov al, [A] should be good.

Comment: And to access the offset of A, try `mov ax, offset A`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments however I still get these errors/warnings:  
 
-pointer expression needs brackets  14
-Extra characters on line  14
 I've updated my code

Comment: Hm... I wonder if the syntax is different in ideal mode.  I don't have a TASM manual ready so I can't say for sure.  Try `mov al, [A+0]` instead?

Comment: @fuz Hey! it works, how ever, how do I put it into ax and not al ? it says that operands do not match, should I use BYTE PTR ?

Comment: @SendHelp Is this a signed or an unsigned number?  Are you programming for an 8086, 80286, or 80386 or newer?  The answer depends on that.

Comment: @fuz 8086 , I was told I can treat each number as signed or unsigned though, I did not learn how to set the mode to 'signed' or 'unsigned'

Comment: If unsigned: clear `ax` or `ah` beforehand.  If signed: use `cbw` to sign extend `al` int `ax` afterwards.  On the 8086 there is unfortunately no instruction to directly load a 16 bit register with an 8 bit quantity from memory.

Comment: @fuz last question, is x86 8086 works in signed? meaning that if I compare something to FFFFh - is it -1 ? so if AX is FFFFh and I cmp to -1 will it output as true?

Comment: Note that there isn't really a “set mode to signed” thing.  A byte in memory is a pattern of bits.  You can interpret this both as a signed or an unsigned number.  The question is about which of the two interpretations you want.

Comment: The `cmp` instruction performs both a signed and an unsigned comparison.  Which one's result you use depends on which conditional jump instruction you use to act on the result.  `jg`, `jge`, `gl`, and `jle` are for signed numbers, `ja`, `jae`, `jb`, and `jbe` are for unsigned numbers.  `je` and `jne` work for both.